# Overriding default struct values

Tags: c++

I have:

```
struct Foo {
  std::string first_name;
  std::string last_name;
  int age;
};

void DoFoo(const Foo& foo) {...}
```

I am writing tests for `DoFoo` and I would like to have default values for the members of `Foo`:

```
Foo default_foo = {.first_name = "John", .last_name = "Doe", .age = 42};
```

Then I have test testing different values, for example:

```
TestInvalidAge() {
  Foo my_foo = default_foo;
  my_foo.age = -1;
  ASSERT_FAILS(DoFoo(my_foo));
}
```

This syntax is annoying because it is verbose to keep copying `Foo my_foo = default_foo` in every test case. I was wondering if there is a way to get the following syntax to work:

```
struct TestFoo : public Foo {
  // Somehow set first_name to "John", last_name to "Doe" and age to 42.
}

TestInvalidAge() {
  ASSERT_FAILS(DoFoo(TestFoo{.age = -1}));
}
```

I don't know how to override and set the default values of base members.

I tried using a default constructor for `TestFoo` in https://onlinegdb.com/tHxetZ6u5 but then the `TestFoo{.age = -1}` syntax doesn't work and I have to write:

```
TestFoo my_foo = TestFoo();
my_foo.age = -1;
```

Which is exactly the syntax I was trying to avoid.

Comment: If you are using the Google Test framework, you could create a fixture for your tests. This way, you can create a specific constructor which will be called prior to your test each time. The function you'd be looking for is `SetUp`

Answer (score 1):

You could initalize the base class in the `TestFoo` default constructor:

```
struct TestFoo : public Foo {
    TestFoo() : Foo{"John", "Doe", 42} {}

    // possibility to use a different age:    
    TestFoo(int Age) : TestFoo() {
        age = Age;
    }
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/78s8b88sK)

Another option:

```
struct TestFoo : public Foo {
    TestFoo() : Foo{"John", "Doe", 42} {}
    TestFoo(const Foo& rhs) : TestFoo() {
        if(!rhs.first_name.empty()) first_name = rhs.first_name;
        if(!rhs.last_name.empty()) last_name = rhs.last_name;
        if(rhs.age) age = rhs.age;
    }
};

DoFoo(TestFoo{} = Foo{.age = -1});
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/z4zE3zqn9)

Comment: "I tried using a default constructor for TestFoo in https://onlinegdb.com/tHxetZ6u5 but then ...". Though, I am not sure if I understand the question either

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Hmm, I missed that one. Odd... :-)

Comment: The problem is you lose all the benefits of designated initializers: What if I want to test first_name, or last_name, or first_name and age, etc.

Comment: @BenjyKessler Since you don't want to add the default values to the base class, you need to add them in a constructor. If you add a constructor, you can't use the base class designated initializers. I added a possible workaround

Answer (score 0):

You can use in-class initializers. They are used as default when no other initializer is provided:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
struct Foo {
  std::string first_name = "Peter";
  std::string last_name = "Parker";
  int age = 42;
};

int main(){
    Foo f{.age = 12};

    std::cout << f.first_name << " " << f.last_name;
}
```

Comment: The default value are only relevant for the test.

Comment: @BenjyKessler I was afraid of that. My point is: Code should be written to be testable from the start. If you cannot test `Foo`, then you should fix it so it can be tested

Comment: @BenjyKessler anyhow, if you cannot / do not want to modify `Foo` you should mention that in the question (unless I overlooked it, then sorry)

Comment: I don't have a problem modifying Foo. It is just a data struct. I just don't want to set test-only defaults in the prod code.

Comment: @BenjyKessler i suppose we are from a different school of thought then. Imho when a class is not easily testable that is relevant for production. I don't want to modify production code "only for testing", I want to modify production code to have testable production code ;)

Comment: @Benjy - Consider this: If you have different defaults in test and production, then what are you actually testing? How do you know that the production code works, if that is not what you tested?